# What books should I read to become politically literate?

Tags: education, reference-request

I'm looking to enhance my political literacy so I can easily navigate political articles and understand debates on various political ideologies. What books would you recommend to help me get started? I'm open to college textbooks too.

Comment: It's difficult to tell where you should get started when one does not know from which level you are starting *from*. For example, are you already familiar with the political system of the country you live in? Which people make which decisions and how do people get into those positions? If not, that might be a good starting point.

Comment: What kind of political articles are you reading? If you're reading things like "Trump moves to 30% lead over DeSantis" or "Supreme Court decision boosts Netanyahu" you're going to need a very different kind of background knowledge to something like "Proposal for modified run-off voting in three-candidate elections" or "Influence of Bakunin on Mao".

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this question gets closed because it is oppinion based.

Here are two books that I think gives a classic historical context of what politics came out of.

- Plato - The Republic
- Machiavelli - The Prince

The first, from 375 BCE is a happy idealist vision of utopia based on righteousness, the second, from 15xx is a realistic backstabbing realism of politics.

The two books won't teach you anything about specific modern ideologies, but it will give enhance your political literacy so you can begin to read contemporary literature.

I hope the question stays open a little and others give a few other books.

Comment: While not books, the crash course videos on history (world/US/European) are also quite good for giving similar background, and gives more modern ideas than Plato and Machiavelli (as well as modern understanding of the contexts). Good for overview if you don't have a strong background.